# How to Write PostgreSQL Stored Procedure to find and kill idle query?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.1, stored-functions

Need to write PostgreSQL Stored Procedure to find and kill Idle queries. Below are the query to find and kill PID:

1. To find list of PID:

   ```
    SELECT pid FROM pg_stat_activity where datname='dbdataanalytics' and state='idle' and state_change<=current_date-1
   ```
2. To kill The PID:

   ```
    SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM idle_connections
   ```

But I need to run this every day automatically. Please help me write stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to PostgreSQL v14 and set the [`idle_session_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-SESSION-TIMEOUT) parameter.  Even better would be to fix the connection leak in your application.

To terminate all connections that have been idle for more then 5 minutes, tun

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE state = 'idle'
  AND state_change < current_timestamp - INTERVAL '5 minutes';
```

Comment: Currently I have PostgreSQL  v12.5. I don't want to upgrade version.

Comment: I need to write Stored procedure to run this query every day. could you please help me on this. I will run this stored procedure using Windows Task Scheduler.